# Parsed string back to date

Tags: string, date, text, casting, type-conversion

I have a date where I parsed it out to append current year - so the date always has current year. the format of this string is DD MMM YYYY (26 Feb 2023)

How can I convert it back so this value reads like a date and not a string

The Formula that was written originally:
CONVERT(varchar(7), from_dt, 106) + CAST(year(getdate()) AS varchar(4))

what I tried
Convert(varchar,(CONVERT(varchar(7), from_dt, 106) + CAST(year(getdate()) AS varchar(4))),101)

Comment: Which language is that? SQL some spreadsheet formula or something else? Please mention and also add the appropriate language tag. It’s your chance to attract the attention of those who know about that language.

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` should do:

```sql
cast('26 Feb 2023' as datetime) as truedate
```